# Selenium 'Показать еще' тыкается лишь один раз

Tags: python, selenium

Поему цикл отрабатывает лишь один раз? Блок успевает прогрузиться ставил sleep в теле цикла

```
    while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='__next']/div/main/section/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button"))).click()
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Причин в целом может быть много, как с прогрузкой, так и с сменой идентификатора блока или в целом проблемы могут быть с его существованием.

Первый вариант будет искать элемент "Показать еще" заново внутри Вашего цикла с помощью `find_element_by_xpath` и пытаться нажать на него.

**Вариант №1:**

```python
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/main/section/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button")
        element.click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        break
```

Второй вариант будет проверять существует ли Ваш элемент "Показать его" вообще, с использованием `find_elements_by_xpath` а уже после будет совершать нажатие..

**Вариант №2:**

```python
while True:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='__next']/div/main/section/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button")
    if len(elements) > 0:
        element = elements[0]
        element.click()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        break
```

Третий вариант будет немного сумбурным, но тоже имеет место быть. Здесь поиск Вашего элемента "Показать еще" будет происходить в каждом новом блоке. А сам поиск будет производиться по тексту.

**Вариант №3:**

```python
while True:
    try:
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Показать еще')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Скорее всего один из этих вариантов должен решить Вашу проблему, во всяком случае, - есть полигон для экспериментов, но в случае чего - напишите комментарий. Или дополните вопрос, чтобы Вам могли оказать более конкретную помощь :)

Comment: вместо `len(elements) > 0:` лучше писать `elements:`

Comment: Не помогает!
Создал гит https://github.com/Asuranay/scraping/blob/main/citilink/main.py 
проблема в классе page_scroll есть еще одна в card, но ее решу через открытие каждой карточки товара отдельно

Comment: Похоже что кнопка вообще не тыкается.

Comment: Опытным путем понял что не грузится блок с пагинацией